# How to make this transition in css?

Tags: css, web

I would like to achieve this curtain-up transition effect by pressing the down arrow. Is it possible to do it in css? If so, how? I can't find the way and I'm not very good at css either. I hope you can help me.

https://www.werkstatt.fr/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use GSAP, a library that creates cool animations through CSS and JS. That could be done easily through MorphSVG plugin in GSAP and does not require that much configuration. Or try first to use Stagger. Check this out.
https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Staggers